# scrolling on cardview making gap in android material design

Tags: android

I have this layout to display the images in card view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

everything looks perfect when screen loads. But when i scroll on screen it makes a gap between two grids vertically. gap size is equal to screen height. in result only 2 grid can be shown on screen after scroll.

Why this behavior? how to fix this?

Comment: You might want to refer this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782333/gap-between-cardviews-increases-on-scrolling

Comment: can you tell me how you are scrolling it? Is it a LIst or recycler View or some ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >
```

By the way  dont use height match_parent for the  root view pf item. It should be wrapContent or some fixed as I can see you ImageViewHeight is 100dp. So adding 16dp padding here,

Use height of LinearLayout as 132 dp.